# XNA Camera rotation / birds-eye-view

Tags: xna, camera, overhead

Okay, this is driving me crazy. I've looked through tons of examples and can't seem to get quite what I need. I'm using XNA and I have a plane of vertices and my camera is up in the sky looking down on the vertices.

What I want is to rotate the camera around on the Y axis, basically get the same result as adjusting its YAW. However whenever I try to rotate around on the Y axis or adjust its YAW nothing actually happens. I can however get the effect I want by creating a Y rotation matrix on the world, but that doesn't feel like the "correct" way of doing it, I want the camera itself to spin and not the world. Here's a code snippet for what I have:

```
cameraPosition = Vector3.Transform(new Vector3(
cameraOffset.X - cameraOffset.X, 
zoomAmount, 
cameraOffset.Z - cameraOffset.Z), 
Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotationAngle)) + cameraOffset;

view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraTarget, new Vector3(0, 0, 1));
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have the camera looking straight down, it sounds like what you want is for the camera to roll in local space. To roll your camera, you must rotate the Up vector you are feeding to the `CreateLookAt()`. Like this:

```
Vector3 newUp = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.UnitZ, Matrix.CreateRotationY(rotationAngle));
view = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraTarget, newUp);
```